# (a∙a)×a, a = (1,1,1) how to get cross product with a result from a dot product

Tags: vectors, cross-product

i know how to do the dot and cross product, but it was my understanding that cross product has to be done between two vectors, however i have a question of this form on my assignment, and i dont understand how to do it as the result of a dot product is a single number.

Comment: $(a\cdot a)\times a$ is almost certainly a typo, perhaps for $a\cdot (a \times a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a\cdot a)\times a$ is definitely wrong.

Email your lecturer or teacher or whatever you call them where you live, they'll send out a correction.

It's most likely $(a\times a)\cdot a$, but I would still get in contact with whoever set the assignment, just to be sure.

Comment: i had a feeling this would be the case, thank you!